# Resize TabView to fit to a Panel

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-extensions

I have a tab view which is inside a LayoutPane. In that tab view, I have 2 tabs. One tab has
1. Output Panel
2. Button

What I would like to achieve is resize height of Output Panel fit to the panel and Button should be at the bottom.

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.x

This is the current UI
[image]

This is the expected one
[image]

Could you please advice is that possible to adjust height of TabView of PrimeFaces? I have applied common ways such as "height: 100%" for tabView level but it doesn't work. When I using F12 to apply styles also not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My advice would be to read about/learn some css and read [ask] and [mcve]. But U suspect that is not what you expect as an answer

Comment: Oh Thanks. I have tried applied multiple way to resize height of TabView of PrimeFaces but no luck for me.

Comment: try to work with `vh` instead of `%`

Comment: this answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979148/5527433

Comment: Thanks. It almost fit what I want, but I can't make the content div scrollable. If I see overyflow-y, the footer also moved down.